# Javascript Function works inside HTML page but doesn't work from external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am trying to place some Javascript code inside a .js file so that I can call it from multiple HTML pages. The problem is, my Javascript code works fine if I place it in a script within the HTML page, but when placed in a external .js file, it simply does not work. I've looked at these questions quite a few times and still cannot find the error.

**Here's the HTML page:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contacts.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/contactsModule.js"></script>
    <title>Hall of Heroes</title>
</head>
<body onload = "contactsModule.getContacts();">



    <!-- Global Header Starts Here -->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="cancel">
            <img src="img/cancel.png" /><!-- if screen is triggered from onboarding, then go back to onboarding screen instead of home -->
        </div>
        <h1>My Contacts</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3>A</h3> <!-- letter header goes here -->

        <!-- Begin Contact Unit -->
        <div class="feed">

        </div>
        <!-- End Contact Unit -->

    </div>

   </body>

   </html>
```

**And here is the .js file:**

```
var contactsModule = (function($){

        function getContacts()
        {
            dbContacts();
        }

        function displayContacts(contactArray){
            window.alert('displayContacts now running!');
            var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(contactArray);
            jsonObject.forEach(function (dat) {
                //Begin Contact Unit
                $('.feed')
                    .append('<div class="feed-img"><img src="' + dat.avatarUrl + '"/>\
                    </div><div class="feed-text"><p><span class="name_highlight">\
                    ' + dat.firstName + ' ' + dat.lastName + '</span></p></div>');
                //End Contact Unit
            });
        }
        function dbContacts() {
            var avatarUrl;
            var firstName;
            var lastName;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.hallofheroesapp.com/php/contacts.php",
                data: {avatarUrl: avatarUrl, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName},
                success: function (response) {
                    window.alert('AJAX ran successfully!');
                    displayContacts(response);
                },
                error: function(response){
                    alert("Error:" + response);
                }
            });
        }
 }(jQuery));
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: are you sure it works in the html file - I don't see anything being returned to the `contactsModule` variable - where does it get it's value..?

Comment: is the end of that function supposed to be `})(jQuery);`?

Comment: @kirinthos both ways work

Comment: I was trimming down the code so it wouldn't be too long. And it works in the HTML file when I just include the functions (getContacts, ... etc.)  - not the module variable

Comment: really? TIL, makes sense though given the associative precedence when I think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from your IIFE. `contactsModule` will then not contain anything, ie equal `undefined`. Also just defining functions doesn't make those functions part of some object, with the exception of globally defined functions. You have to assign them, or define them as part of an object literal

Your code should be something like

```
var contactsModule = (function($){
    return {
        getContacts: function() {
             /* code */
        },
        displayContacts: function(contactArray){
             /* code */
        }
        dbContacts function() {
             /* code */
        }
    };
 }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     ///// your code here...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

... change ...

```
<body onload = "contactsModule.getContacts();">
```

... to ...

```
<body>
```

... and add event handler using jquery ...

```
(function($){

        function getContacts()
        {
            dbContacts();
        }

        /* ... etc ... */

        // use jquery's onready handler
        $(getContacts);

 }(jQuery));
```

Comment: What is the purpose of $(getContacts); near the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Easy thing when you research on google.
Your Js code loads before the DOM loads. Which should be the other way around. So you have to use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //only jQuery is recommended, global JavaScript functions outside!
});
```

Also JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  //global function outside! 
});
```

Only this way you can be sure that your DOM is loaded before your jquery finds your elements.

Comment: What do you mean when you say global functions outside?

Comment: It means that your global functions should be outside of this event handler. So you can call the functions otherwise you cannot.